# Python indent issue with function

Tags: python, function, shell, indentation, interpreter

I'm making a function in python the code structure works fine, but when I put that code structure inside a function, that throw me indent error and my indent is fine what could be???

Ok this is my code:

```py
def userAgentCtl():     
    userAgents={
        1:'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36',
        2:'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36',
        3:'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Debian; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0',
        4:'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E14LightSpeed [FBAN/MessengerLiteForiOS;FBAV/280.0.0.32.106;FBBV/241469109;FBDV/iPhone12,5;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iOS;FBS13.6.1;FBSS/3;FBCR/;FBID/phone;FBLC/fr;FBOP/0]',
        5:'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; MAR-LX3A Build/HUAWEIMAR-L03A; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like GeckoVersion/4.0 Chrome/85.0.4183.81 Mobile Safari/537.36 UMCE/v1.6_245-android'
        }
    options=userAgents.keys()
    for opt in options:
        print "Option number >", opt, "  User agent =", userAgents[opt], "\n"
    try:
        numberOption=int(raw_input(">"))
        if numberOption == 0 or numberOption > 5:
                print("That number is not in the options\n")
                userAgentCtl()
    except:
        print("Must be a number do not letters\n")
        userAgentCtl()
    return userAgents[numberOption]
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LBn9.png)

[Code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXErb.png)

Comment: Can you share the *exact* indentation error (traceback). Share the entire code using the editor, not images.

Comment: If this is a new project you should use Python 3. [Python 2 died earlier this year](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)

Comment: Lex, [use three backticks (`) to format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). I find that easier than adding 4 spaces of indent for Python code.

Comment: Don't use recursion where a `while` loop will suffice.

Comment: @FishingCode here is the complete code https://github.com/TitanHero/facebookBotCtl/blob/master/chatbot.py

Comment: LoL a lot of thanks for the tip @PranavHosangadi, is the first time that I post in stackoverflow, and I don't knew that here is accepted the markdown syntax, very cool thanks ✌️

Comment: how did you create indents? Maybe you mixed spaces and tabs and now it looks correctly but it makes problem. In some editor you can find functions "convert tabs to spaces". And many editors you can select few lines and press `tab` to make indents in all lines.

Comment: Yeah @furas maybe is that I gonna try it thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Already I fix this this, the problem was the taps, better use the spaces, looks like was a mess between taps and spaces, cool.